# How can I find the distribution of a recursive relation with two parameters?

Tags: probability-distributions, finite-fields, computational-complexity, recursion

Suppose we have a recursive relation, e.g. $G(n,m) = G(n-1,m) + G(n, m-1)$, with some initial points where $n,m \in \mathbb{Z}^{+}$ and $F$ is a finite-field, e.g. $\mathbb{Z}_p$ for a prime $p$. Also $G: \mathbb{Z}^{+} \times \mathbb{Z}^{+} \rightarrow F$. There are enough initial points such that make the recurrence stop in finite number of steps for finite $m$ and $n$.

I want to compute the distribution of this relation over the field $F$ and then compare it to some other distribution, e.g. uniform or Gaussian distribution. The question is how can I do that? I have searched a lot, but could not find an answer. Even search terms are appreciated.

The reason I want to do this is proving hardness of the problem whose solution is finding $n$ and $m$ when $F(n,m)$ is given.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you specify the function a bit better? What initial points (seems to me that you may need several)? Are the values of $F$ also in the same finite field, or are they real numbers, or what? If your $n,m$ range over an extension field of $\Bbb{Z}_p$, then that recurrence relation is not going to define the function $F$, unless you give its value at very many initial points.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I have edited the post, changed the function name to $G$ to prevent confusions and given the form of $G: F \times F \rightarrow F$.

Comment: Are $n,m$ ranging over the positive integers (as you say at one point) or over the field $F$ (in which case you have to start worrying about things like whether the recursion forces $G(1,1)=G(1,1+p)$ for the function $G$ to be well defined).

Comment: One of the problems I have with this is that for the recursion formula to define the function at a single point you need to know the value at two other points. So if only a single initial point is given, then the recursion never gets going?

Comment: For initial points, we can think of having enough points, so the recursion stops at some finite point for finite $m$ and $n$.

Comment: and yes! $m$ and $n$ are rangine over $\mathbb{Z}^+$

Comment: So $G$ is a function from $\Bbb{Z}^+\times\Bbb{Z}^+$ to $F$?

Comment: yeah! that's the case. sorry for such a typo. :-(

Comment: Presumably one defines $G(0,m)=G(n,0)=0$ for all $m,n\in\Bbb Z^+$, so that the only initial value needed is $G(0,0)$. Or one could specify initial values for all the $G(0,m)$ and $G(n,0)$.

Comment: Yeah! You are correct.